# Does Cloud Run require a webserver such as flask or fast api to function if using python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

This is my code and Docker file, I have not create a webserver, I think that is the problem is there a smooth way to do this if I am just trying to pull data from an API into big query as Flask and Fast API are for building web pages as far as I know.

I'm not sure exactly how you could bend something like Flask to act as a webserver to pull data from an API without having to set up a Hello world page or something of that sort?

The error I am currently getting when I deploy it is 'Cloud Run error: The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable.' However it does run successfully for 4 minutes which I know is the cut off time for listening before cloud run stops.

````
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 8080
ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser


# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["python", "app.py"]




import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
import google.auth
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import schedule
import time

def req():
    r = requests.get("https://api-eu.mouseflow.com/websites/e768ed54-c09b-48dc-bf49-beda12697013/pagelist",
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth("************", "***********"))


    parsed = json.loads(r.text)
    print(json.dumps(parsed['pages'], indent=4, sort_keys=True))


    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(parsed['pages'])
    

    #df.to_csv('mousedata3.csv')#
    df.to_gbq('Mouseflow.Mouseflow_ETL', if_exists='replace', project_id='api-data-pod')
    #Sent info to cloud securely#
    
# Time
#schedule.every().day.at("06:30").do(req)
schedule.every(30).seconds.do(req)
#schedule.every(45).seconds.do(dt)
#schedule.every(5).minutes.do(req)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)```
````

Comment: Right.  This is not a net server in any way.  It's just a web consumer.  It doesn't need to open a port at all.  Remove the EXPOSE and ENV lines.

Comment: Have a look at Cloud Run [jobs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs). These should be closer to your need in running some task.

Comment: You may want to consider using [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) in conjunction with Cloud Run jobs to schedule the repetition.

Comment: It was Cloud Run Jobs @DazWilkin thanks for that I didn't even know that existed but I can see it's a fairly new service. I am having some problem with cloud scheduler though. Which I am pretty sure is related to the URL. So the code runs with no problem in Cloud Run Jobs. I just can't get Cloud Scheduler to execute the code as it says it can't find the job.

Answer (score 0):

We have something similar/related. We have a Python/Flask app deployed to Cloud Run. It has one route which is secured (meaning you can't access the service by just typing the url in your browser). Cloud Scheduler invokes the service endpoint once a day and when the service endpoint is invoked, it fetches data from datastore, processes it and stores it back.

The above setup consists of 2 bits - a `Dockerfile` and a `main.py` file which houses the code that is run.

We documented creating and deploying the Dockerfile on our blog [here](https://nocommandline.com/blog/step-by-step-guide-to-deploying-your-app-to-google-cloud-run/) and securing it [here](https://nocommandline.com/blog/how-to-secure-your-cloud-run-service/). The last line in the Dockerfile causes gunicorn to run the `main.py` file. `main.py` contains the route which when invoked fetches and processes the data.